# How do you add a second possible variable to a clean url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I have created a htaccess rewrite code for URLs so when a user goes to `myurl.com/testing/` it shows them `index.php?page=testing` however I would like to have a second or maybe third page so it could look like `myurl.com/testing/2832/9283` and would show users `index.php?page=testing&var1=2832&var2=9283`.

This is the code I currently have:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]*)/$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2
```

This works but I want to make the variables optional. If I do not have a second variable (i.e. just `myurl.com/testing/`) then it says it cant find the file.

Comment: This is the 3rd time you posted that question! 3rd question on this topic today!!!

Comment: I thought I should have opened a new one because it was too different to the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# 3-level deep parameters
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?(/)?$ /index.php?page=$1&var1=$3&var2=$5 [QSA,L]
```

1. This rule will not touch already existing files and folders.
2. This rule will rewrite:

   - `/help/tracking/123456/` => `/index.php?page=help&var1=tracking&var2=123456`
   - `/help/tracking` => `/index.php?page=help&var1=tracking&var2=`
   - `/help` => `/index.php?page=help&var1=&var2=`

You were having `page=index.php` because your rule rewrites already rewritten URLs (A lot of people forgetting, that when rewrite happens, it goes to next iteration and starting to test all rules **again**). This rule has conditions (extra checks) to ignore already existing files and folders.

Comment: i deleted my other answer, this works fine other than %s how would i fix this?

Comment: @Yesterday What do you mean by `%s`. Please give an example (URL that does not work). if you have online URL that will be great.

Comment: like this http://spareslist.com/login.php/previous/http%3A%2F%2Fspareslist.com%2F with the percentages it gives a 404 without it it is fine.

Comment: @Yesterday Problem with such URL that it is **rejected by Apache straight away**, mod_rewrite is not even get started. The `/` in `http://domain.com/` part needs to be escaped properly.

Comment: @Yesterday I saw some question mentioned the same or similar problem but cannot find it now. The suggestion was to use `base64_encode()` function to encode that part when building URL and `base64_decode()` when processing by script. Basically, such URL will look like `http://spareslist.com/login.php/previous/aHR0cDovL3NwYXJlc2xpc3QuY29tLw==`. This particular problem has nothing to do with URL rewriting -- Apache rejecting your URL `http://spareslist.com/login.php/previous/http%3A%2F%2Fspareslist.com%2F` as invalid straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set multiple RewriteRules for each case?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3
```

Comment: this is being really strange now, if you go to http://spareslist.com/home/asd/g you can try out what you suggested. i have used your code exactly and on the index.php page it just prints the get array. For some reason it only used the get variable page with a vaule of index.php :/ Any idea why?

Comment: i've changed it to: RewriteRule /([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3

Comment: but now when you try it it works but you have to put something first ie. spareslist.com/random/page/var1/var2

Comment: The code in your second comment is not correct. What happens if you replace the preceding `/` with `^`?

Comment: I just told you, it doesnt do anything other than set page to be index.php.